# Using WikipediaAPI

Tags: python, chatbot, wikipedia

I'm making a chatbot using AIML.
Is there any tag in AIML that can search with Wikipedia?
I'd like to use Python to make it possible to search Wikipedia when certain questions are typed in.
Can anyone help me? T_T~~

Comment: Have you checked this package: https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/ ?

Comment: @aminrd No, I haven't T_T thx a lot~I'll give it a try.

Comment: I found [Pywikibot](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Pywikibot_-_Python_3_Tutorial/Data_Harvest) (official WikiMedia library) to be very useful and easy to use, will also retrieve information from wikidata (in same query) parse the information to class object attribute for easy information extraction.

Answer (score 0):

i personally tried [this](https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/) for doing some search with Wikipedia on python. Managed to run several common use cases such as searching page.

Hope this helps!